# How to save what I have selected into a new table in KDB

Tags: select, kdb, q-lang

I have selected something in a table how to put what I have selected into a new table?

Select code is like:

```
select vwap:(sum PRICE*VOLUME)%(sum VOLUME) by SYMBOL,DATE from trade
```

Answer (score 3):

Save it to a variable with the `:` operator

```
newTable:select vwap:(sum PRICE*VOLUME)%(sum VOLUME) by SYMBOL,DATE from trade
```